# Maven error: "Non-parseable POM: start tag not allowed in epilog"

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using Maven and Bing API to create a web search interface for a class project. When compiling the files through the command prompt, I am receiving a weird error.

This is the command line results when compiling:

```
C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project>mvn compile exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project\pom.xml: start tag not allowed in epilog but got b (position: END_TAG seen ...</build>\r\n</project>\r\n<b... @46:3)  @ line 46, column 3
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project  (C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project\pom.xml: start tag not allowed in epilog but got b (position: END_TAG seen ...</build>\r\n</project>\r\n<b... @46:3)  @ line 46, column 3 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException

C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project>
```

Below is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.websearch.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-project</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>New Project Using SchemaCrawler</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>us.fatehi</groupId>
      <artifactId>schemacrawler</artifactId>
      <version>${schemacrawler.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <schemacrawler.version>11.02.01</schemacrawler.version>
    <skip.signing.artifacts>true</skip.signing.artifacts>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>7</source>
          <target>7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <!--Your comment
            Replace the mainClass with the path to your java application.
            It should begin with com and doesn't require the .java extension.
            For example: com.bingwebsearch.app.BingWebSearchSample. This maps to
            The following directory structure:
            src/main/java/com/bingwebsearch/app/BingWebSearchSample.java.
          -->
          <mainClass>com.WebSearch</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <!--Your comment
                    Replace the mainClass with the path to your java application.
                    For example: com.bingwebsearch.app.BingWebSearchSample.java.
                    This maps to the following directory structure:
                    src/main/java/com/bingwebsearch/app/BingWebSearchSample.java.
                  -->
                  <mainClass>com.WebSearch.java</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-cognitiveservices-websearch</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I am new to this and seem to be stumbling through this assignment. I have been following a tutorial from microsoft's website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: For example, you have a `<build>` tag outside `<project>` (which is the root element).

Comment: So should the <project> tag go at the very end of the file?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have multiple root (top-level) elements while XMLs must have only one. In POM, the root element is `<project>`. So your other top-level elements should be moved inside `<project>`. Then you should merge your multiple `<build>` elements into one.

Please learn more about XML and read the [POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) which tells you exactly what elements can each element contain. Try to understand the structure and then you can solve these kind of problems yourself. Using an IDE would be a huge help for you as it points out the errors while you're editing the file, and it may suggest a solution.

Your final POM structure should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.websearch.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-project</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>New Project Using SchemaCrawler</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>...</dependency>
    <dependency>...</dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>  
  <properties>
    ...
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>...</plugin>
      <plugin>...</plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I have reformatted my POM file as you suggested. I am now receiving a new error.      C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project>mvn compile exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\zacha\Desktop\java-project\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'plugins' (position: START_TAG seen ...<plugin>\r\n    <plugins>... @82:14)  @ line 82, column 14.                 Unfortunately I am being told my POM file is too long to post in the comments

Comment: Looks like you have `<plugins>` inside `<plugin>`? That surely doesn't make sense. Try to understand what the words `plugins` and `plugin` mean: `plugins` is the list and `plugin` is the list item. And again, **please read the POM reference** which tells you exactly what elements can each element contain. Finally, if your new situation is too long for a comment, it should be a new question. But if you **try to understand the structure**, you can solve these kind of problems yourself. Also an IDE can be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same maven errors but I have a valid pom.xml file.  The only thing happened was that I hit the CTRL+SHIFT+F while viewing the pom file in STS editor.  Afterward spring boot gave me tons of errors complaining about this and that.  I tried to fix the problems but not the one pointing at the .  It kept complaining about invalid content after the project end tag but nothing was there.

So, instead of trying to troubleshoot the problem that is not really a problem, I shut down and restart STS tool.  The problem magically cleared. I got a clean build of my project and it worked magically without further troubleshooting.

Comment: OP cannot figure out if this would solve his/her problem, as it's not clear this is related to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the position of 'parent' tag in the pom. 
It should come after the 'dependencies' closing tag.

Comment: I do not have a <parent> tag in my pom. Should that be included? And if so, what does it contain?

Comment: There's no `<parent>` element in the question, and having one would not solve any of the problems.

Comment: AND parent tag does not have to be after dependencies. I always list my parent near the top, before the dependencies